# Javascript directed acyclic graph library? (Graph visualization is NOT necessary)

Tags: javascript, graph, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dataset which is best represented by a graph.  It consists of nodes of 6 or 7 different "types" with directed edges (dependencies on one another, guaranteed not to have cyclic dependencies).  The dataset is essentially a template of a layered configuration, and the user needs to be able to select bits and pieces of the configuration from different layers which are desired, and have the dependent bits be brought in automatically.

The general UI need is for a user to select or un-select items from multi-select boxes (one such box for each node type), and have "depended-on" items in the other boxes become selected or unselected as needed.  I need to be able to pull down the dataset from the server, let the user select the desired bits (with the dependency processing being done in javascript on the client side for responsiveness), and then submit the result back when they are finished.

The dataset is large and complex enough that actually showing it as a graph would be overwhelming and confusing to the user. Only basic graph traversal operations are needed, since all that is required is to cascade selections out the dependencies.  (For example, a user un-selecting a node would result in that nodes dependencies becoming unselected if there were no other selected node which still depended on them. A user selecting a node would result in all of that node's dependencies becoming selected.)  A simple depth or breadth first search following directed edges from the start node will suffice to visit all affected nodes. If I can follow edges either direction, bonus.  (If not I can easily generate an edge-reversed graph and use that when needed.)

I have dug around on here and found references to a number of javascript graph visualization libraries, but most of these discussions seem to interpret "graph" as "chart" and I have no charting needs here. My digging has led me to this list:  Raphael, protovis, flare, D3, jsVis, Dracula, and prefuse.  From this list it looks like jsVis or Dracula might have the underlying graph constructs I need if I just ignore the visualization side, but it isn't clear to me from the documentation if that is the case.  I have to rule out a few others because I cannot bring in any flash dependencies.  Unfortunately I don't have time to prototype things with this many libraries. (I will be digging into jsVis and dracula more though, barring some handy input here.)

If anyone has experience with something from that list and believes that the graph portion of it can be used independently of the visualization portion, that will certainly meet my needs. If there is some other library I could use that meets my needs, that would be great too.  One final requirement regarding licensing: the library needs to be "free" in a non-copyleft way - So ideally Apache v2.0, BSD, MIT, or something like that.

Comment: Did you end up implementing your own solution? If so, is it available anywhere?

Answer (score 8):

I haven't used it, but you might want to check out [data.js](http://quasipartikel.at/data-js/). It's an MIT-licensed library with a range of data-structure utilities. In particular, it includes [`Data.Node`](http://quasipartikel.at/data-js/#section-61) and [`Data.Graph`](http://quasipartikel.at/data-js/#section-121):

> A Data.Graph can be used for representing arbitrary complex object graphs. Relations between objects are expressed through links that point to referred objects. Data.Graphs can be traversed in various ways.

Comment: Thanks, I took some time this morning to look through this and I'm not sure it will really do what I need.  It is very light on documentation and the example wants me to be running CouchDB and node.js.  Since all I really need is simple tree traversal I think I might roll my own, but if I do use data.js I will come back and mark this as the answer.